# Laravel working with relations

Tags: join, laravel-5

I've three tables called:"

User
Rittenregistratie
karakterrit

A user has one or multiple Rittenregistratie and a Rittenregistratie has 
one Karakterrit.

This are my models:

User model:

```
  public function Rittenregistratie()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rittenregistratie');
    }
```

Rittenregistratie model:

```
 public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function karakterrit()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\karakterrit');
    }
```

Karakterrit model:

```
public function rittenregistratie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\rittenregistratie');
    }
```

When I search for a specific id in my controller for the rittenregistratie I do it like this:

```
$rittenregistratie = Rittenregistratie::whereId($id)->firstorFail();
```

And when I want to show the karakterrit of that rittenregistratie in my view I do it like this:

```
$rittenregistratie->karakterrit_id
```

But how do I make sure that I don't see a number but the value from that row?

EDIT

Maybe I've explained it a bit to complicated.

Normally I would have used Joins to achieve this. 
I've three tables **user,Rittenregistratie,Karakterrit**

Rittenregistratie looks like this

```
Id (primary key)
kmstand (int)
van (text)
naar(text)
karakterrit_id (foreign key)
```

Karakterrit looks like this

```
Id (primary key) 
rit (text)
```

Rittenregistratie.karakterrit_id is the foreign key of karakterrit_id. Now is my question how do I show karakterrit.rit?

Comment: As a monolingual English speaker, what are “Rittenregistratie” and “Karakterrit”?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that it's dutch. Rittenregistratie is where you've driven with your car so date,from,to. And karakterrit is for example if you drove private or for business purpose.

Comment: Just a note: you should be using StudlyCase for class names, but camelCase for method names (i.e. the `User` method should be lowercase).

Comment: “But how do I make sure that I don't see a number but the value from that row?” What value are you wanting? As we can’t see your schemas so don’t know what columns are available.

Comment: @MartinBean please see my edit, hope it's now clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the model and not the value, call it like this. Eloquent will fetch the relation for you via a magic method.

```
$rittenregistratie->karakterrit
//or
$rittenregistratie->karakterrit()->first();
```

EDIT:
Since it returns the model, to get its values you simply do `$rittenregistratie->karakterrit->rit`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think I've explained it a bit to complicated please see my edit.

Comment: @jamie Added an example.

Comment: Thanks but then I receive the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'karakterrit.rittenregistratie_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `karakterrit` where `karakterrit`.`rittenregistratie_id` = 3 and `karakterrit`.`rittenregistratie_id` is not null limit 1) (View: D:\wamp\www\resources\views\ritten\rit.blade.php)

Comment: @jamie if u r nt following the conventional way for naming foreign keys then u have to mention foreign_key and local_key in the relationships. For example: return $this->hasMany('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');